# Duplicate PHP Emails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

The emails sent using php **are being sent twice**. My application is in Codeigniter and I was using its mail.  I have now, for testing purposes, created the function below in a Codeigniter controller, and I'm still sending two emails.

Here is the test function:

```
public function testSend(){
        $to      = "myEmail@gmail.com";
        $subject = "HTML email Test from testSend";

        $message = "
<html>
<head>
<title>HTML email</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>This email contains HTML Tags!</p>
<table>
<tr>
<th>Firstname</th>
<th>Lastname</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>John</td>
<td>Doe</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
"; 

//$message = $this->getMessage($data);
// Always set content-type when sending HTML email
        $headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
        $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

// More headers
        $headers .= 'From: <myEMail@whistclub.org>' . "\r\n";
//$headers .= 'Cc: myboss@example.com' . "\r\n";

        $result = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

        if ($result)
        {
            echo "mail sent sucessfully";
        } else
        {
            echo "mail failed";
        }

        exit;
    }
```

The above function is essentially a copy and paste from the PHP mail manual page.

I doubt that it is relevant, but if I attempt to send a mail from a script based on the function without a function call it fails.

Comment: Can you be sure that testSend() isn't being called multiple times?

Comment: A simple test would be to add something unique (e.g. the return value of `uniqid()`) somewhere to your email body. If PHP is actually sending the email twice, that unique value will be the same. If the `testSend()` function is being called twice, you will have two different values.

Comment: sometimes browser plugins refresh page and this process is hidden from you , e.q. make sure that you load this page once .

Comment: Your function is okay. Maybe you are calling the function two times somewhere else? + CI has it's own Email class too. you can try use it.

Comment: Why not use coeigniter built in email library?

Comment: How is `testSend()` called?

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.

Here are my answers.

I don’t think, pretty sure, the function is called twice.  The command line in the browser shows the url/index.php/testSend and I just hit enter.

My application uses the Codeigniter email system, but I am testing with php mail to eliminate the Codeigniter complexity. 

The duplicate emails show up in Safari, Chorme and iOS devices, so I don’t think it is a plugin.  

I will test the unique item idea, when I get to my computer.

Comment: OK, we are making progress.  Using rickdenhaan='s suggestion I put the output of uniqid() into the email and the output is different in the two emails. So, that means the testSend() function is being called twice. I use Chrome and have only tested using Chrome.  I just ran the program in the latest fireFox and it only sent one email! I think we have found the problem--plugin or something in Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

The duplicate emails were caused by something in Chrome and not a php or Codeigniter issue.  Using fireFox resulted in no duplicates.  The program runs in a cron method on a server so it would never have sent the duplicates.